# According to what property does collect() sort its output?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Is the collection given by using the aggregation "collect()" on many nodes, sorted after a specific property or id, or is the order random? I've looked at the [documentation](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/aggregation/#aggregation-collect) but didn't find anything helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you build up the paths for what you are collecting.

You can use an `ORDER BY` to ensure the elements are ordered. For example:

```
// Don't specify order
MATCH (p:Crew) 
RETURN COLLECT(p.name) AS people

> [Neo, Morpheus, Trinity, Cypher]
```

In the case above the ordering ends up being according to the internal node `id`, which we can confirm by collecting that value along with the name property:

```
MATCH (p:Crew) 
RETURN COLLECT({name: p.name, id: id(p)}) AS people

> [ {name:"Neo", id:0},  {name:"Morpheus", id:1},  {name:"Trinity", id:2},  {name:"Cypher", id:3}]
```

But we can use an `ORDER BY` to explicitly specify the order for the elements in our collection:

```
// Order by name, ascending
MATCH (p:Crew) 
WITH p ORDER BY p.name ASC 
RETURN COLLECT(p.name) AS people

> [Cypher, Morpheus, Neo, Trinity]
```

There is a simple example here: http://console.neo4j.org/r/bqxlmx